# Html mail can't send using CodeIgniter SMTP

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I am trying to send HTml Mail using Codeigniter .
The mail is sending fine But I got the result as follows

```
$config = array(  
                 'protocol'  => 'smtp',
                 'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                 'smtp_port' => '465',
                 'smtp_user' => 'no-reply@xxxxx.in',
                 'smtp_pass' => 'Mypassword',      
                 'mailtype' => 'html',
                 'charset'  => 'utf-8',
                 'newline'   => "\r\n",
                 'priority' => '1'

                  );
      
       $this->load->library('email',$config); 
       $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

  $this->email->from($from_email, 'Doctor M'); 
 $this->email->to($to_email);
 $this->email->subject('Doctor M | Verification');
 $this->email->message($content);
if($this->email->send()) {echo "ok";}
```

[image: Email Iam getting]

```
$content_head   =   '<html>
                                    <head>
                                                    <title>Doctor M</title>
                                                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
                                                    </head>
                                                    <body bgcolor="#ffc107" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="background:#ffc107;">
                                                    <table bgcolor="#ccccff" width="800" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" style="background: #fff;padding: 50px;border: 1px solid #dddddd;">
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                    <img src="'.base_url().'assets/media/images/logo.png" alt="'.base_url().'" width="75" height="116" border="0px normal #000;"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr><td height="10"></td></tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td width="800" align="left" valign="top"><table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                    <tr>
                                                   
                                                    <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#666; padding: 0 10px;">';
                        $content_tail           =  '</td>
                                                    
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </table></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td align="left" valign="top">
                                                    </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                    <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#fff" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#000; padding:5px 10px;">&copy;'.date('Y').'. '.base_url().' . All Rights Reserved.</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                    </body>
                                                    </html>';
                          
                                               
                        $content = $content_head.'<p>Hi  <strong> '.$this->input->post('name').  '</strong><br></p>';
                        $content .= '<p>&nbsp;</p>';
                        $content .= '<p><b>You have successfully registered to Ayush Hardtalk.</b></p>';
                        $content .= '<p>&nbsp;</p>';
                        $content .= '<p>Please click the link below to join the event: <br></p>';
                        $content .= '<p>'.$this->input->post('link').  '</p>';
                                                 
                                                
                        $content .= '<p><table cellspacing="0">';
                      
                     
                        
                        $content .= '<tr><td><br>We hope you will continue to associate with us <td><td>';
                        $content .= '</table><p>';
                        $content .= '<p>Holistically yours<br/>';
                        $content .= '<p>&nbsp;</p>';
                        $content .= '<p>&nbsp;</p>';
                        $content .= '<p>Team Ayush valley<br/>';
                        
                        $content .= '</p><br/>'.$content_tail;
```

Comment: Please add the lines how the mail content is added

Comment: @AaronJunker I am getting  correct format when I use mail protocol

Answer (score 0):

Put your HTML email content in a PHP file.

```
$data['email_param'] = ['name' => 'srinivas'];
$content = $this->load->view('html_email_file', $data, TRUE);  
$this->email->message($content);
```